# Should I set JAVA_HOME if java is already added to PATH?

Tags: java, ant, path, environment

Why some applications (like Ant) need JAVA_HOME variable if java is already added to PATH?

And following that thought, why, when installing Ant we must also add ANT_HOME variable, even if we already added Ant to PATH?

Why instead of this:

```
export ANT_HOME=/Library/apache-ant-1.9.4
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

Shouldn't we just use

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Library/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
```

Are there more reasons other than readability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PATH variable can contain multiple different versions of Java or Ant. The JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME variables uniquely identify the version of Java or Ant used when starting from the command line.

Also, these environment variables are typically used in shell scripts that start the corresponding program, and it's much easier to deal with an environment variable that points to a single path, rather than a collection of paths.

Comment: Are you sure that if we have multiple versions of java in the PATH, it will choose the one that JAVA_HOME points to, not the latest placed in the PATH?

Comment: This depends on what "it" is and how it is implemented. If you run "java" from the command line, it will run the binary which is the latest in the PATH.